# how to get array of product ids list for particular category in magento

Tags: magento

I was trying to get **list of product ids** but failed.

It should be get without any loop.

How to get **array** of product ids for particular category.

Comment: show your code what you have tried

Comment: @Devendrapathi have you tried any code.please share.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($Catid);
 $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore)
            ->addCategoryFilter($cat)->addFieldToSelect('entity_id');
```

Here $collection will give list product ids

Answer (score 0):

Find Products from specific category -

```
$categoryIds = array(5,6);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

hope this might help you.